# How do I only set the default parameter values for a report if it is running as an email subscription

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that has start date and end date as parameters. I want the parameters to be set to yesterday's date if the report is being run as an email subscription and they must be left empty if the report is being viewed in a web browser by a user so that the user can select the date range without the report automatically rendering the first time. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It takes in part of the state parameter settings Subscription date: 
Use default value and assuming the parameters specify the date in the format: "date" -1

normal to this date will only offer and he will be able to choose another date if needed